# Unable to view links in Windows live Mail while composing (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hyperlink, windows-live-mail

When I am composing a message in Windows live Mail and I want to include a link I can do so easily however the link does not show up as a link when I'm composing the e-mail. After I send the e-mail and I then look at Sent Mail the desired link info shows up as an active link. I have tried using both Hyperlink from the insert toolbar and from the right-click  context but hyperlink is grayed out.

Is this normal or is there a fix to make it do the expected?

Thank you.

Ross

Comment: I don't use WLM, but if it's anything like Word then can't you press Ctrl and click the link?

Comment: Alas, no.That doesn't work.